# What's the link between Eulerian/Lagrangian approaches and macroscopic/microscopic point of view?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, reference-frames, definition, flow

From what I know, in fluid dynamics, the [Eulerian approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field) studies points that are fixed in space and time, while the [Lagrangian approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lagrangian_and_Eulerian_specification_of_the_flow_field) studies individual particles and follows them.
Is it correct to say that the Lagrangian approach is a microscopic point of view, and the Eulerian one is a macroscopic one?

If not, can you provide examples of Eulerian systems with a microscopic point of view, or Lagrangian ones with a macroscopic view?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Lagrangian or Eulerian formulations make no specific distinction in size—they merely relate to whether you are tracking the properties at a point or volume of space (Eulerian), or the properties of a point or volume of “something” which moves along with whatever flow field that causes said “something” to move (Lagrangian).

One could, for example, construct a Eulerian control volume analysis associated with a microscopic spherical volume—nothing about the mathematics or physics says such an analysis fails at specific scales. Likewise, one could construct a Lagrangian analysis around a block of solid material—which is in fact the way solid mechanicists develop mathematical models of elasticity.

Comment: Oh okay, so my definition of Lagrangian is wrong, you don't follow particles, you follow points that move with the flow.

Comment: Yup—the idea is that by following flowing points associated with locations of particles, you wind up following those particles. For a discrete object, one can construct a “coordinate system” for positions/particles within the object, which is the central concept of material coordinates.