# Dervie a lagrangian formulation from an eulerian One

Tags: reference-frames, mathematical-physics

in the solidification of a binary alloy : X18%Y . where the nominal concentration of Y in the alloy phase is 18% , the goal is to determine the  variation of < C>  ;the average concentration over time in the langrangian frame of reference
from this eulerian formulation of < C> variation : 
$$ \frac {d<C>} {dt}  + \nabla C_l .V = 0 $$

Where : $$ < C> = (g_l-k_p(1-g_l)C_l$$

What would be the lagrangian formulation : $$ \frac {D<C>}{Dt} =  ?  $$, Cl is the liquid concentration , gl is the liquid fraction and kp is constant ( Equilibrium partition coefficient) , the simplest case of a lagrangian formulation from an eulerian one is $$ \frac {Dx}{Dt}(lagrange : total-  derivative)=\frac {dx}{dt} + \nabla x .V (euler: partial-derivative + advection ) $$ but in the equation i posted $$\nabla C_l V $$ has to be reformulated in order to contain $$\nabla <C>.V $$ to get the total derivative $$ \frac {D<C>}{Dt} $$ that's where i got stuck , 
thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please take time to write our more details about background and context. Also it helps to show what you've tried and where you're stuck!

Comment: Hi , thanks for pointing out the missing context and where i got stuck . please let me know if there is still something unclear . thanks

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/512359/2451